# React useState delays update after user initial input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I understand that React's `useState` hook is an asynchronous method, hence why it has a callback. However, I want to make the initial user input update (state is updated after only after second input) the state when the `handleChange` method is triggered. How do I do that -- update react without delay?

**code:**

```
import React, { useState, createRef } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import DocumentHead from "../DocumentHead";
import Button from "../Button";
import phoneLady from "../../assets/images/phoneLady.jpg";
import setBgImage from "../../utils/setBgImage"

export default function register() {
   
   const pageName = "Regsiter";
   
   const [form, setForm] = useState({
        title: "",
        firstName: "",
        lastName: "",
        emailAddress: "",
        phoneNumber: "",
        dateOfBirth: "",
        organization: "",
        password: "",
        confirmPassword: "",
        finalFormIsSlidedIn: false,
        buttonIsDisabled: true,
        termsAndConditionsIsChecked: false,
    });

const handleChange = (e) => {
        const target = e.target;
        const name = target.name
        const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value

        setForm((state) => {
            return {
                ...state,
                [name]: value
            }
        }, console.log(form))

}

const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
}

return (
    <>
       <DocumentHead title={pageName} />
       <section>
<div id="orderbook-form">
                        <form className="h-full">
                            <div className="pt-20 pb-10 px-12">
                                <h1 id="orderbook-home" className="text-center mb-10 leading-6 md:hidden">
                                    <Link to="/" className="text-gray-400">Orderbook Online</Link>
                                </h1>
                                <div className="px-4 sm:px-0 mb-3">

                                    <h2 className="text-lg font-medium leading-6 pb-3 sm:pb-2">
                                        Nice to meet you,
                                    </h2>
                                    <p className="mt-1 text-sm text-gray-600">
                                        create an account to start using
                                        Orderbook
                                    </p>
                                </div>

                                <div className="grid grid-cols-1 gap-5">
                                    <div
                                        id="registration-steps"
                                        className="col-span-12"
                                    >
                                        {/*Registration -- First step*/}
                                        <div
                                            id="first-step-fields"
                                            className="col-span-12 grid grid-cols-1 gap-4"
                                        >
                                            <div className="col-span-12">
                                                <select
                                                    id="title"
                                                    name="title"
                                                    autoComplete="title"
                                                    className="mt-1 focus:ring-white block w-full sm:text-sm bg-gray-300 form-field"
                                                    value={form.value} 
                                                    onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
                                                >
                                                    <option defaultValue="Please choose">
                                                        Please choose
                                                    </option>

                                                    <option value="Mr">
                                                        Mr
                                                    </option>
                                                    <option value="Miss">
                                                        Miss
                                                    </option>
                                                    <option value="Mrs">
                                                        Mrs
                                                    </option>
                                                    <option value="Ms">
                                                        Ms
                                                    </option>

                                                    <option value="Dr">
                                                        Dr
                                                    </option>
                                                    <option value="Other">
                                                        Other
                                                    </option>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>

                                            <div className="col-span-12 grid grid-cols-2 gap-4">
                                                {/*Fix grid*/}
                                                <div className="col-span-1">
                                                    <input
                                                        type="text"
                                                        name="firstName"
                                                        value={form.firstName}
                                                        id="first-name"
                                                        autoComplete="first-name"
                                                        placeholder="First name"
                                                        className="mt-1 focus:ring-white block w-full sm:text-sm bg-gray-300 form-field"
                                                        onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
                                                    />
                                                </div>

                                                {/*fix grid*/}
                                                <div className="col-span-1">
                                                    <input
                                                        type="text"
                                                        name="lastName"
                                                        value={form.lastName}
                                                        id="last-name"
                                                        autoComplete="last-name"
                                                        placeholder="Last name"
                                                        className="mt-1 focus:ring-white block w-full sm:text-sm bg-gray-300 form-field"
                                                        onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
                                                    />
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <div className="col-span-12">
                                                <input
                                                    type="text"
                                                    name="emailAddress"
                                                    value={form.emailAddress}
                                                    id="email-address"
                                                    autoComplete="email"
                                                    placeholder="Email address"
                                                    className="mt-1 focus:ring-white block w-full sm:text-sm bg-gray-300 form-field"
                                                    required
                                                    onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
                                                />
                                            </div>

                                            <div className="col-span-12 text-right">
                                                <span
                                                    id="next-field-button"
                                                    className={`form-slide-button ${
                                                        form.finalFormIsSlidedIn
                                                            ? "hidden"
                                                            : ""
                                                    }`}
                                                    onClick={() =>
                                                        slideFinalFormIn()
                                                    }
                                                >
                                                    Next{" "}
                                                    <i
                                                        className="fa fa-long-arrow-right"
                                                        aria-hidden="true"
                                                    ></i>
                                                </span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        {/*Registration -- Final step*/}
                                        <div
                                            id="final-step-fields"
                                            className="grid gap-4"
                                            ref={finalFormStepRef}
                                        >
                                            <div className="col-span-12">
                                                <input
                                                    type="tel"
                                                    name="phoneNumber"
                                                    id="phone-number"
                                                    value={form.phoneNumber}
                                                    pattern="[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}"
                                                    autoComplete="phone-number"
                                                    placeholder="Phone number"
                                                    className="mt-1 focus:ring-white block w-full sm:text-sm bg-gray-300 form-field"
                                                    required
                                                    onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
                                                />
                                            </div>

                                            <div className="col-span-12">
                                                <input
                                                    type="text"
                                                    id="data-of-birth"
                                                    name="dateOfBirth"
                                                    value={form.dateOfBirth}
                                                    autoComplete="date-of-birth"
                                                    placeholder="Date of birth (MM/DD/YYYY)"
                                                    className="mt-1 focus:ring-white block w-full sm:text-sm bg-gray-300 form-field"
                                                    onFocus={(e) =>
                                                        (e.target.type =
                                                            "date")
                                                    }
                                                    onBlur={(e) =>
                                                        (e.target.type =
                                                            "text")
                                                    }
                                                    onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
                                                />
                                            </div>

                                            {/*<div className="col-span-12">
                                                <input
                                                    type="text"
                                                    id="organization"
                                                    name="organization"
                                                    value={form.organization}
                                                    autoComplete="organization"
                                                    placeholder="Organization/Company"
                                                    className="mt-1 focus:ring-white block w-full sm:text-sm bg-gray-300 form-field"
                                                    onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
                                                />
                                            </div>*/}

                                            <div className="col-span-12 grid grid-cols-2 gap-4">
                                                <div className="col-span-1">
                                                    <input
                                                        type="password"
                                                        id="password"
                                                        name="password"
                                                        value={form.password}
                                                        autoComplete="password"
                                                        placeholder="Password"
                                                        className="mt-1 focus:ring-white block w-full sm:text-sm bg-gray-300 form-field"
                                                        required
                                                        onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
                                                    />
                                                </div>

                                                <div className="col-span-1">
                                                    <input
                                                        type="password"
                                                        id="confirm-password"
                                                        name="confirmPassword"
                                                        value={form.confirmPassword}
                                                        autoComplete="confirm-password"
                                                        placeholder="Confirm password"
                                                        className="mt-1 focus:ring-white block w-full sm:text-sm bg-gray-300 form-field"
                                                        required
                                                        onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
                                                    />
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <div className="col-span-12 text-left">
                                                <span
                                                    id="previous-field-button"
                                                    className="form-slide-button"
                                                    onClick={() =>
                                                        slideFinalFormOut()
                                                    }
                                                >
                                                    <i
                                                        className="fa fa-long-arrow-left"
                                                        aria-hidden="true"
                                                    ></i>{" "}
                                                    Previous
                                                </span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div className="col-span-12">
                                        <div className="flex items-start">
                                            <div className="flex items-center h-5">
                                                <input
                                                    id="terms-and-conditions"
                                                    name="termsAndConditionsIsChecked"
                                                    type="checkbox"
                                                    className="focus:ring-white h-4 w-4 text-indigo-600 border-black rounded"
                                                    required
                                                    onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
                                                />
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="ml-3 text-sm">
                                                <label
                                                    htmlFor="terms-and-conditions"
                                                    className="font-medium text-black"
                                                >
                                                    By signing up, you agree
                                                    to
                                                </label>{" "}
                                                <Link to="/">
                                                    Orderbook’s Terms of Use
                                                    & Privacy Policy
                                                </Link>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div className="col-span-12 mt-1">
                                        <Button
                                            type="submit"
                                            title="Sign up"
                                            buttonClass="register-button auth-button"
                                            buttonDisabled={
                                                form.buttonIsDisabled
                                                    ? true
                                                    : ""
                                            }
                                        />
                                    </div>

                                    <div
                                        id="login-existing-account"
                                        className="col-span-12 mt-1 account-signal"
                                    >
                                        <div className="text-center">
                                            Already have an account?{" "}
                                            <Link to="/login">Log in</Link>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
       </section>
    </>
);
}
```

Comment: can you elaborate on - "I want to make the initial user input update (state is updated after only after second input) the state when the handleChange method is triggered." as it makes no sense to me

Answer (score 0):

I think you can not reach to top 0, you can use a form library for less render and manage all states wisely, please check [hook-form](https://react-hook-form.com/)